# TFS: Select two files to merge

Tags: tfs, merge

In TFS, I normally right-click a file and select Merge to merge it. What if I have two files I want to select to include in a single merge? How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If the two file you're trying to merge have an existing branch/merge relationship, you can right click the source file -> Merge and choose the desired target file from the dropdown.

If not, and you just want a simple 2-way diff, right click one of the files -> Compare, then enter the name & version of the file to diff against.  At this point it's up to whatever client diff tool you've configured to do something constructive with the two files sans common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I just tried it - although you can multi-select items in Source Control Explorer, the context menu then disables Merge.

You can, however, right-click a folder and select Merge.

It looks like if you have two files among many in a folder you would have to merge them individually (or possibly use the command-line [TF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx?ppud=4) tool).